# In ios 7 UIPicker/calendar is not looking good,how to change the look and feel of Calendar in monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, uidatepicker

[image]

How to change look and feel of Calender for ios7.

Answer (score 3):

According to [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIDatePicker.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIDatePicker):

> You cannot customize the appearance of date pickers.

If you want it to look different, you'll have to implement your own `UIPicker`.